# Linux server beeping during operation

Tags: hardware-raid

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 headless server with Cockpit as a management tool, it's been running fine for a few months since I built it until yesterday when I came home to find it beeping. Two short beeps repeated.

The server continues to run and perform as expected, there are no errors in the logs I can check via Cockpit. I shutdown and booted Memtest86 to check it wasn't a memory issue and the RAM passed the tests (I did only run 3 of 4 as it took over an hour). I reseated the RAM before I did the test.

I did a full power down and it stopped the beeping for 24 hours, but it's come back again. I also tried using a different plug socket, though I didn't expect this to do anything.

My hardware is:

- AsRock H470M-ITX motherboard
- Intel i5-10600
- 2x Integral IN4T8GNELSI 8GB DDR4 RAM 2666MHz
- 1x Samsung Evo 970 Plus
- 1x WD WD20EFRX-68E
- In RAID 5: 2x WD WD40PURZ-85T, 1x WD WD40PURX-64G
- InWin IW-MS04 case with Mini-SAS 6Gb/s SFF-8087 backplane

Software:

- Cockpit

In docker:

- Plex
- Nextcloud
- Nginx Proxy

Some hints as to where to look for errors, or what could be causing it would be extremely helpful. Also it's worth saying I didn't install a beeper and I believe the board doesn't have one built in.

Comment: The User Manual for this motherboard says this about controlling "boot beeping" in the bios:  "Boot BeepSelect whether the Boot Beep should be turned on or off when the system boots up. Please note that a buzzer is needed."   So, if you haven't installed a "buzzer", then it and the interpretation of them as "beep codes" are not the source of the beeps.  Additionally, unless you installed speakers, the beeps may not be coming from this PC.

Comment: Cheer Tony. I definitely haven't installed a speaker, and there are no speakers for audio as it's headless and sat in a cupboard. However, it is definitely the source of the beeps; and after at least 48 hours I've come home today to find it beeping again and still no idea why.

Comment: If you didn't connect a chassis speaker, didn't connect a speaker via I/O Panel speaker port, and didn't connect a beeper... I'm at a loss of how the sound is being produced, much less its meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who gave advice. MoBo indeed does not have a buzzer, so I took a look around the case and the included backplane does.

Two beeps is a "Temperature fail", though it doesn't give any help beyond that. I will order in a small fan and connect it to the backplane fan control and see if that helps through this hotter UK weather.